# Hammer.js swipe doesn't work until button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I'm using hammer.js library to add swipe gestures for touch devices.

My code is:

```
var bodyElement = document.getElementById('body');
    var swipe = new Hammer(bodyElement);
    swipe.on("swipeleft", function() {
        $(".close-button").click();
    });
    swipe.on("swiperight", function() {
        $(".open-menu").click();
    });
```

What I'm trying to do is to click on one button element when swipe right and click on another button element when swipe left, but this is not working until I click on button first (.open-menu) manually, after that everything working fine (swipe left, swipe right clicks on buttons).

I have the ID 'body' on body element, I want to swipe working when user swipes anywhere.

Am I missing something with hammer.js? What could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that trying to swipe on 'body' causes Hammer to throw the following error:

*hammer.js:222 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null*

I guess you need to add the swipe listener on an existing element that isn't body.

The following code works for me:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Test</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" src="hammer.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrap" style="position:fixed;top:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:alert ('Open Button');" class="open-menu">Open</a> - <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:alert ('Close Button');" class="close-button">Close</a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
    var bodyElement = document.getElementById ('wrap');
    var swipe = new Hammer (bodyElement);
    swipe.on ('swipeleft', function ()
    {
        $(".close-button").click ();
    });
    swipe.on ("swiperight", function()
    {
        $(".open-menu").click();
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Basically I've wrapped the links into a div called 'wrap' and the swiping is tied to that div. With the styles I've applied to the div, it stretches across the entire page so it basically acts like 'body' would anyway.

I hope that helps!